# How to get SVG image coordinates in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, svg-icon

I am displaying SVG image in Lightning, when I click on particular part in image I need to get co ordinates of that SVG image. Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261304/how-to-get-the-click-coordinates-relative-to-svg-element-holding-the-onclick-lis) it might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add onclick event on svg element in lightning but there is a way. You can wrap your svn inside a div and then add onclick event to that div. 
Then you can bind onclick event with that div. In order to read ordinates of the SVG image you can use the event object. So in order to determine if the event is fired from a area within the svn we can put a check on event.srcElement.nodeName and identify that event is coming from the desired svg image.

Consider below code snippet:

**Lightning Component Code-**

```
<aura:component >
<div>
    <div >
        <h1>HELLO SVG</h1>
    </div>
    <div aura:id="svg_content"  onclick="{!c.clicked}" >
    <![CDATA[
        <svg width="100" height="100" >
           <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40"  stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="red" />
           Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
        </svg> 
    ]]>
    </div>
    <div >
        <h1>HELLO SVG</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

**Component's Renderer Code:**

```
({
    // Your renderer method overrides go here
    afterRender: function(component, helper) {
        var svg = component.find("svg_content");
        var value = svg.getElement().innerText;
        value = value.replace("<![CDATA[", "").replace("]]>", "");
        svg.getElement().innerHTML = value;        
    }
})
```

This is used because as of now you can not add svg tag directly in Lightning component.

**Lightning Component Controller:**

```
({
    clickedFunction : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(event);
    },
    clicked : function(component, event, helper){       
        if(event.srcElement && event.srcElement.nodeName == 'circle'){          
            console.log('Inside Circle');
            console.log("x: "+event.clientX+" y:"+event.clientY);
        }else{
            console.log('Outside circle');
        }
    }

})
```

**Output obtained:**

Here you can see we are now able to capture events from SVG image.

[image]

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks kiran for your solution. Can I get clicked image part source code from SVG. EX: If I click on any part of image, I need to get that particular part(circle/rectangle) svg source code.